# Order of the words to emphasize meaning

Tags: differences

I would like to ask what is the difference between these two sentences:

> a) We need to prioritize badly injured people.
>
> b) We need to prioritize people badly injured.

Is b) stressing more the fact that there are people injured?

Comment: Both 'badly injured people' and 'people badly injured' are noun phrases which function like nouns. Hence, grammatically both are equal, and correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no inherent difference in meaning between the two options. But Option A reads more clearly.

The noun phrase in this sentence contains three words: *people*, *injured*, and *badly*. The noun is *people* and the other two words act as modifiers. The word *badly* is modifying *injuired*, and together they modify *people*.

The [common model](https://linguapress.com/grammar/noun-phrases.htm) for noun phrases is to place modifiers before nouns. So the preferred syntax here is *badly injured people*.

Comment: I guess the questioner knows those kinds of grammatical things. What matters to him/her might be whether there is any practical difference in use between a) and b), and if so, what it is. So an expected answer might be "Yes/No" first of all, and then its reason.

Comment: Good call @Toothy -- I have updated to answer the question directly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another option...

If you want to emphasise that you’re prioritising specifically those with worse injuries you could phrase it...

> we need to prioritise people injured badly.

This states that people with superficial injuries are less of a priority than those with worse injuries.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "We need to prioritize people badly injured." strikes me (native BrE speaker) as badly translated from some other language. The first phrase " We need to prioritize badly injured people." is clear.

If you wanted to emphasise people (who are badly injured) as distinct from, say , animals, then you could say " We need to prioritise those people who are badly injured". The word 'those' helps to define where you emphasis lies.