# What's the correct structure of this sentence

Tags: syntactic-analysis, sentence

I have a list of programs that are installed. What's the correct way to say this?

"**The number of programs installed**" or "**The number of installed programs**"?

What's the correct structure? And why is that?

Comment: Why do you think that they are not both correct?

Comment: The thing is, for me both are correct and give the same idea. But usually I'm wrong, so that got me think if one is more correct than the other.

Comment: _The number of programs installed_ >> _The number of programs which are installed_ (**uses a reduced relative clause construction**); _The number of installed programs_ >> Here the noun *programs* is directly modified by the adjective *installed*. Both are different ways of saying the same thing, though the second is to be slightly prefered.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order of the words to emphasize meaning](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/520583/order-of-the-words-to-emphasize-meaning) 'We need to prioritize badly injured people' vs 'We need to prioritize people badly injured.'